# Client for handlersocket server

Tags: java, mysql

I wrote a simple client for handlersocket server, but I'm not a professional Java programmer and would like to know the opinion of Java developers on my code.

Well I have not yet decided how to implement a class `HSResult`.

My project is [here](https://github.com/komelgman/Java-HandlerSocket-Connection)

`HSResult` store initial query and answer as `List` of `ChannelBuffer`s, where each `ChannelBuffer` it chunk of response according to the [protocol](https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/blob/master/docs-en/protocol.en.txt).

```
package kom.handlersocket.result;

import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import kom.handlersocket.query.HSQuery;
import kom.handlersocket.core.SafeByteStream;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HSResult {
    private final HashMap<HSQuery, List<ChannelBuffer>> resultSet = 
        new LinkedHashMap<HSQuery, List<ChannelBuffer>>();
    private final Charset charset;

    public HSResult(Charset charset) {
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    public void add(HSQuery query, List<ChannelBuffer> result) {
        resultSet.put(query, result);
    }

    public void debug() {
        SafeByteStream output = new SafeByteStream(1024, 65536, charset);

        for (Map.Entry<HSQuery, List<ChannelBuffer>> entry: resultSet.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().encode(output);
            System.out.print(new String(output.toByteArray(), charset));
            output.reset();

            for (ChannelBuffer buffer : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.print(buffer.toString(charset));
                System.out.print("-");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code in the question. (Check the FAQ.)

Comment: it too much. I would like to know how well I use a collection and how well I use Netty.

Separately, I wanted to board the best way to make interpreting the results in class HSResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The type of the `resultSet` reference could be simply `Map<...>`:

   ```
   private final Map<HSQuery, List<ChannelBuffer>> resultSet
   ```

   Reference: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
2. Instead of the `Map<HSQuery, List<ChannelBuffer>>` I'd use [Guava's Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It was 
   [designed for this case](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).
3. Constructors and methods should validate their input parameters.

   ```
   public HSResult(Charset charset) {
       this.charset = charset;
   }
   ```

   Does it make sense to have a `charset` with `null`? If not, check it and throw an `NullPointerException`. (*Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)